# Send complex object to controller. Part of object's properties is completed from another partial view

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3, mapping

I have an object model for my view that contains appointment's information and appointment's recurrence. Something like this:

```
 public partial class AppointmentModel
 {
      public appointment Appointment { get; set; }
      public appointmentRecurrence Recurrence { get; set; }
      ...
 }
```

From my main screen I'm completing Appointment fields and submit AppointmentModel model. Also from this screen I open a dialog (partial view strongly typed to appointmentRecurrence) that contains information regarding recurrence of the appointment.

My question is: How can I send my appointmentRecurrence model to my "main" model to fill Recurrence property and submit to my action from controller? I can't submit the appointmentRecurrence until I create an appointment, so my complex object must be filled with all fields.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you finish completing fields in appointmentRecurrence popup, then you should write Appropriate data in appointment view in hidden fields and at the end, submit all fields(including fields migrated from popup)

EDIT:

Main Form:

```
<form id="mainForm" action="/MyController/MyAction" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="Firstname"/>
    <input type="text" name="Lastname"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="popupData" id="popupData"/>
    <input type="button" value="save" onclick="SavePopupData();"/>
</form>
```

Partial Popup:

```
<form id="popupForm" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="Firstname"/>
    <input type="text" name="Lastname"/>
    <input type="button" value="save" onclick="SavePopupData();"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function SavePopupData() {
        //Close popup
        $('#popupData').val($('#popupForm').serialize());
    }
</script>
```

In MyController:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(MainFormModel mainFormModel, string popupData)
{
    var popupModelData = new PopupModel();
    UpdateModel(popupModelData, ConvertToFormCollection(popupData));
}

private FormCollection ConvertToFormCollection(string formData)
{
            var collection = new FormCollection();
            var keyValues = formData.Split('&');
            foreach (var keyValue in keyValues)
            {
                var res = keyValue.Split('=');
                collection.Add(res[0], res[1]);
            }
            return collection;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but I'm looking for a more elegant method considering the fact that I would have to complete 59 properties from my pop-up. I would like to use some mapping feature or JSON object if possible.

Comment: You can collect this information and put in one hidden input. serialize form and put it in hidden input

Comment: So you suggest that I need to create a JSON object (or something similar with a serialized object) and send it to my screen. Next step is sending the "complex" object to controller. How do I copy the Json object to my Recurrence property of my model?